# Does this function create a memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Does the following function `make_map` constitute a memory leak in C++?

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> make_map() {
    return *new std::map<std::string, std::string> { "a", "1" };
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    auto my_map = make_map();
```

It is my understanding that calling this function many times repeatedly would result in many of these maps being allocated to the "free store". My reasoning is that, each time `make_map` is called, the following happens

1. Memory is allocated in "free store" for the map object.
2. The map's constructor is called with the initializer list.
3. `my_map` is copy constructed from the dynamically allocated map.

In my head it seems like this constitutes a memory leak because dynamically allocated map in `make_map` never goes out of scope so it's destructor is never called and the free-store memory is never deallocated. So calling this 100 times would result in 100 copies of this map allocated in the "free store". Is this correct?

Comment: The short answer is "Yes" :) Just use `return std::map<std::string, std::string> { "a", "1" };` Get rid of the `*new` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a leak.  Since you return by value the object returned by the fucntion is a copy of the object you created with `new` so you can no longer access that new object to delete it thus having a memory leak.  If you switched to returning by reference and then captured that reference then you could delete it like

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>& make_map() {
    return *new std::map<std::string, std::string> { "a", "1" };
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    auto& my_map = make_map();
    // stuff
    delete &my_map;
}
```

But you shouldn't design your code like that.  Instead you just want

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> make_map() {
    return {{"a", "1"}};
}
```

Which causes no leaks and is guaranteed to be RVO'ed (Return Value Optimized) in C++17.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this function create a memory leak in C++?

Yes. You allocated with `new`, and discarded the pointer. It can no longer be recovered, and can therefore never be deleted, and therefore the memory has been leaked.

Your reasoning is also correct.